# How do I use the output of a command in a for loop in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I'm trying to use the output of this in a for loop:

```
$wc -l example.mgn | awk '{print $1}'
12
```

however, I get this:

```
for i in {1..`wc -l example.mgn | awk '{print $1}'`}; do echo $i; done
{1..12}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brace expansion occurs before any other type of expansion, you can only include literal values in braces. For example, `{1..12}` is valid, but you can't replace either 1 or 12 with a command that produces a number.

Instead, use

```
for ((i=1; i<= $(wc -l < example.mgn); i++)); do
    echo "$i"
done
```